# Unable to Dynamically Change Primary Color in Less at Runtime

Tags: javascript, less, antd, darkmode, ant-design-pro

I am currently facing challenges altering the primary color in Less dynamically during runtime. Despite trying various approaches.

I attempted to modify the primary color in Less using the `@primary-color: black` command. I was expecting the primary color to change to black, but the expected result did not materialize.

I am using the following versions of libraries.

Less version 3
Ant Design (antd) version 4
Umi version 2
Ant Design Pro version 2

I would greatly appreciate any insights or potential solutions to address this issue. Thank you for your support.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.